# How to compare 2 values and print the next cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 Excel files and I'm trying to compare two numbers (one has 7 digits and the second 5 digits).

For example in an excel file I have the following number 1234567 and in another file I have 12345 in one cell in another cell I have the remaining digits 67. I want to compare the first number with the second and if they are the same i need to identify the cells that have the value 67 and to print what is in the next cell.

They are constantly changing so I'm having problems getting this right

I made this formula but it doesn't work properly. Did I miss something?

```
=IFERROR(IF(INT(RIGHT(A5;2))=VLOOKUP(INT(LEFT(A5;5));'Path[file.xls]
    Sheet1'!$S$3:$AA$200;2;FALSE);VLOOKUP(INT(LEFT(A5;5));'path[file.xls]
    Sheet1'!$S$3:$AA$200;3;FALSE);VLOOKUP(INT(LEFT(A5;5));'path[file.xls]
    Sheet1'!$S$3:$AA$200;5;FALSE));"")
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description and sample formula, I pieced together some sample data in **File.xls**.

[image]

Note by the right alignment, these are true numbers. This is important. A [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) or [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) will not find `RIGHT(A2, 5)` amongst numbers; it has to be `--RIGHT(A2, 5)`. With 7 digit numbers in another workbook, I used this standard formula.

```
=INDEX([File.xls]Sheet1!$S:$AA, MATCH(--LEFT(A2, 5), [File.xls]Sheet1!$S:$S, 0), MATCH(--RIGHT(A2, 2), INDEX([File.xls]Sheet1!$S:$AA, MATCH(--LEFT(A2, 5), [File.xls]Sheet1!$S:$S, 0), ), 0)+1)
```

Note that every values is expected to be found. If this is not the case, then an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) should be used to handle non-matches.

The results were as follows.

[image]

Comment: Great formula.  Just note that the `VLOOKUP` in the sample formula is working as `INT` is applied to the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` results thus returning a number or error which is taken care by the `IFERROR`.